# Console.Log and Discord Message displaying different results

Tags: random, discord, bots, console.log, dice

I have a relatively basic set of code here that is programmed to roll 3 dice and give me the results whenever I type "/roll" in discord.

However, the results displayed on my command terminal are always different from those in the discord message from the bot.

```
  async execute(interaction) 
    {
        var num = 3;
        num = Number(num);
        
        function rollingDice(num) {
          // make the dice rolling "num" times.
          // return the results.
          var diceResults = "";
          for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            var resultOfEachDice = "";
            resultOfEachDice = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
            diceResults += resultOfEachDice + ", ";
          }
          var lastComma = diceResults.lastIndexOf(", ");
          diceResults = diceResults.slice(0, lastComma);
        
          return diceResults;
        }
        
        var diceResults = rollingDice()

        console.log("Rolled " + num + " dice: " + rollingDice(num));

        console.log(process.argv);

        await interaction.reply('You rolled: ' + rollingDice(num));
```

So I will type /roll and my terminal will say I rolled "3, 5, 2" while the message would have something entirely different like "1, 6, 4".
This happens every time I run the command and I am not sure what the issue is.

Comment: You are not using the saved results from rollingDice(), instead you call it once for logging to console and once for Discord message, that is why you get different result.